# Beamer: Show all previous \tableofcontents items and gray out future items. Also: Remove subsections from ToC and then fix distances between items

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to present a ToC in Beamer which shows the previous items and grays out future items. I cannot quite get it to work however. Here is a MWA:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{totcount} % Get the last number of a counter
\regtotcounter{section}
\newcounter{mytmp}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\frame{\tableofcontents}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{2.1}
\frame{\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]}
\section{Section 3}
\setcounter{mytmp}{\thesection}
\stepcounter{mytmp}
\frame{%
    \tableofcontents[sections={1-\thesection},hideallsubsections]
    \tableofcontents[sections={\themytmp-\totvalue{section}},currentsection]
}
\section{Section 4}
\frame{}
\section{Section 5}
\frame{}
\section{Section 6}
\frame{}
\section{Section 7}
\frame{}
\section{Section 8}
\frame{}
\subsection{8.1}
\frame{}
\subsection{8.2}
\frame{}
\section{Section 9}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows:

1. A standard ToC.
   [image: Output from ToC in section 1]
2. A Toc using the `hideallsubsections` option. Why is the distance between items increased? How can it be fixed?
   [image: Output from ToC in section 2]
3. A ToC nearly showing what I want to accomplish. Why is the distance between 3 and 4 so narrow? How can it be fixed? Once again, the `hideallsubsections` in the visible list messes up the distance between items. If all of this can be fixed, would it be possible to create at better solution, where `\setcounter{mytmp}{\thesection}` and `\stepcounter{mytmp}` don't need to be written every time, i.e. creating a new `\mytableofcontents` command which solves everything?
   [image: Output from ToC in section 3]

I have also tried surrounding the `\tableofcontents` command with `\setbeamercovered{still covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}},again covered={\opaqueness<1->{100}}}` and `\setbeamercovered{still covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}},again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}}`, alas without success. This works for itemize lists though!

Answer (score 5):

I think the following source code gives the results that you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{totcount} % Get the last number of a counter
\regtotcounter{section}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\makeatother
\AtBeginSection{%
\frame{%
  \tableofcontents[sections={1-\thesection},hideallsubsections]%
  \unskip\vskip0.5em
  \tableofcontents[sections={\the\numexpr\thesection+1\relax-\totvalue{section}},currentsection,hideallsubsections]
}}
\begin{document}
\frame{\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{2.1}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\section{Section 5}
\section{Section 6}
\section{Section 7}
\section{Section 8}
\subsection{8.1}
\subsection{8.2}
\section{Section 9}
\end{document}
```

I use `\numexpr` to do calculation, use `etoolbox` to patch `beamer` code.

[image]